# _id is not tied to specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into an issue where regardless of what component is clicked in a list of Job items, it returns the id of the last element only.

I have a key passed to the mapped list:

```
let activeListings = jobs.filter((job) => !job.isArchived);
activeListings?.map((job) => {
            return (
              <div key={job._id} className="bg-white w-8/12 py-4 my-4">
                <Job
                  job={job}
                  setJob={setJobs}
                  handleShowDetailsToggle={handleShowDetailsToggle}
                  archiveToggler={archiveToggler}
                  setShowingResumeModal={setShowingResumeModal}
                  setShowingCoverLetterModal={setShowingCoverLetterModal}
                  showingResumeModal={showingResumeModal}
                  showingCoverLetterModal={showingCoverLetterModal}
                  getJobs={getJobs}
                  key={job._id}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })
```

In the Job component, there is a button that when clicked opens a modal to select a file to upload and a preview.

Regardless of which Job component the Upload component is called from, it always gets passed the job._id from the final Job component listed.

Here is the resume modal component that opens on the button click:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Upload from "../../Upload";

const AddNewResumeModal = (props) => {
  const { setShowingResumeModal, job, getJobs, id } = props;
  const [previewSource, setPreviewSource] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="resume-modal-background">
      <div className="resume-modal-container">
        <button
          className="close-modal-btn"
          onClick={() => setShowingResumeModal(false)}
        >
          &times;
        </button>
        <h1 className="resume-modal-title">Upload Resume</h1>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(job._id)}>Test2</button>
        <Upload
          resume={true}
          setShowingResumeModal={setShowingResumeModal}
          job={job}
          getJobs={getJobs}
          previewSource={previewSource}
          setPreviewSource={setPreviewSource}
        />
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNewResumeModal;
```

and the Upload component it renders:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Viewer } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";
import "@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css";

const URL = "http://localhost:8000";

const Upload = (props) => {
  const {
    setShowingResumeModal,
    job,
    getJobs,
    previewSource,
    setPreviewSource,
  } = props;

  const [fileInputState, setFileInputState] = useState("");
  // const [previewSource, setPreviewSource] = useState("");

  const handleFileInputChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    previewFile(file);
  };

  const previewFile = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setPreviewSource(reader.result);
    };
  };

  const handleSubmitFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!previewSource) return;
    uploadFile(previewSource, job._id);
    getJobs();
    setShowingResumeModal(false);
  };

  const uploadFile = async (base64encodedFile, id) => {
    console.log(base64encodedFile);
    console.log(id);
    try {
      await fetch(`${URL}/upload/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64encodedFile }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="file"
          name="pdf"
          id="pdf"
          accept=".pdf"
          onChange={handleFileInputChange}
          value={fileInputState}
          className="form-input"
          onClick={() => console.log(job._id)}
        />
      </form>
      <div className="preview-container">
        {previewSource ? (
          <div className="viewer-container">
            <Viewer fileUrl={previewSource} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="no-preview-source">Preview area</div>
        )}
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleSubmitFile}
        type="submit"
        className="upload-submit-btn"
      >
        Upload Resume
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

Please help me understand how to correctly pair each job listing so that the correct id of the job is passed to the backend.

Comment: I don't have a sandbox to test this, and I can't see the code for <Job>.

However bugs of the type "returns the id of the last element only" are usually the result of some sort of closure, or pass-by-reference shared variable that has been declared outside a loop. 

Try putting console.log() statements for the value of `job._id` through the data flow. Hacky workaround might be to clone `job = { ...job }` to ensure a copy rather than a shared object pointer

Comment: Show what `jobs` are or how they are defined. Also can you remove code that is not needed and only provided the problematic code with everything that's needed. I can't tell what part of your code is the one that's problematic, I just see chunks of code posted.